# Magento 2 apply discount on tax issue + FPT

Tags: magento, coupon, discount, tax, magento2.1

Firstly I am using Magento 2.1.8 version

I'm facing an issue with tax total amount and discount from coupon code. Whenever I apply a discount coupon on cart, tax amount stays the same. I have read a few posts saying that Magento 2 option:

My options:
**Catalog Prices**: Excluding tax
**Apply Customer Tax**: After discount
**Apply Discount On Prices**: Exclude tax

Moreover product have FTP (Fixed product taxes) set.

Maybe someone know this issue and have a fix for it? Also it would be great if someone could confirm that they also facing the same issue (add discount - tax stays the same, using FPT)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research and discussions, we got a conclusion. Apparently FPT (fixed product tax) meant to be **Fixed** and it doesn't change dynamically. Changing it dynamically would break it's logic. If someone disagrees - please write you own opinion to the comments below.

I have checked it with the product without FPT, only with simple tax class, taxes were changing as discount was applied.

If you still know how to apply a discount on FPT product taxes, please share your knowledge, there might be people who still need to do it (sometimes clients can be demanding).

Comment: This is very useful to me too, can you please tell where to set up FPT. thanks

Comment: Enable it in the store configuration and add it when you are in the product edit page in the admin. Try to search documentation for it on the M2 official documentation